# KeyError with pandas json_normalize when opening JSON file, but not with JSON embedded in code (JSON to CSV)

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

This works (normalize data inline):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        "action_type": "add_chat_item",
        "author": {
            "id": "abcde",
            "images": [
                {
                    "id": "source",
                    "url": "https://www.example.com"
                },
                {
                    "height": 32,
                    "id": "32x32",
                    "url": "https://www.example.com",
                    "width": 32
                },
                {
                    "height": 64,
                    "id": "64x64",
                    "url": "https://www.example.com",
                    "width": 64
                }
            ],
            "name": "user1"
        },
        "message": "the first user sent this",
        "message_id": "abcde",
        "message_type": "text_message",
        "time_in_seconds": -999,
        "time_text": "-0:00",
        "timestamp": 2000
    }, 
    {
        "action_type": "add_chat_item",
        "author": {
            "badges": [
                {
                    "icon_name": "moderator",
                    "title": "Moderator"
                }
            ],
            "id": "abeee",
            "images": [
                {
                    "id": "source",
                    "url": "https://www.example.com"
                },
                {
                    "height": 32,
                    "id": "32x32",
                    "url": "https://www.example.com",
                    "width": 32
                },
                {
                    "height": 64,
                    "id": "64x64",
                    "url": "https://www.example.com",
                    "width": 64
                }
            ],
            "name": "user2"
        },
        "message": "message from the user two",
        "message_id": "abeedk",
        "message_type": "text_message",
        "time_in_seconds": -111,
        "time_text": "-1:11",
        "timestamp": 100003
    }
]

norm = pd.json_normalize(data)
norm.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, columns=['timestamp','author.name','message'])
```

And this works, with the above data saved as file.json (read file and outputs columns including full `author` column, to CSV):

```
import pandas as pd

with open('file.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
     df = pd.read_json(inputfile)

df.to_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, columns=['timestamp','author','message'])
```

But this doesn't work with that same file:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('file.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
     df = pd.read_json(inputfile)

norm = pd.json_normalize(df)
norm.to_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, columns=['timestamp','author.name','message'])
```

I get a bunch of errors, the last lines of which are:

```
raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['timestamp', 'author.name', 'message'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

This results in the same error:

```
with open('file.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
     df = pd.json_normalize(inputfile)

df.to_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, columns=['timestamp','author.name','message'])
```

This results in a successful CSV, but only with new lines:

```
with open('file.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:
     df = pd.json_normalize(inputfile)

df.to_csv('file3.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I expected to output the `author.name` column in the CSV when reading from the JSON file. Instead, the code errors out when it reads the file and normalizes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `json.load` instead `pd.read_json` first:

```
import json

with open('file.json', encoding='utf-8') as inputfile:    
    data = json.load(inputfile)
    
norm = pd.json_normalize(data)
norm.to_csv('file.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False, 
            columns=['timestamp','author.name','message'])
```

**Details**:

```
print (norm.head(2))
     action_type                    message message_id  message_type  \
0  add_chat_item   the first user sent this      abcde  text_message   
1  add_chat_item  message from the user two     abeedk  text_message   

   time_in_seconds time_text  timestamp author.id  \
0             -999     -0:00       2000     abcde   
1             -111     -1:11     100003     abeee   

                                       author.images author.name  \
0  [{'id': 'source', 'url': 'https://www.example....       user1   
1  [{'id': 'source', 'url': 'https://www.example....       user2   

                                       author.badges  
0                                                NaN  
1  [{'icon_name': 'moderator', 'title': 'Moderato...
```